# Multiple calls of JS function w/ parameters

Tags: javascript

I've got a JS function that edits fill inputs' values.

I'm fetching the input's value by an ID that is the parameter of the function and the functions is called on click.

My problem is that when I click to edit the first input, it works, but then I want to edit the third one.. it edits the first and the third one?

How can I reset my functions to only edit the third ?

Here's my JS function

```
function editTicket(id) {
let toEdit = id;
document.getElementById("inputRow" + toEdit).style.backgroundColor = "#6C63FF";
document.getElementById("inputRow" + toEdit).style.color = "#fff";
$("#imgtoCenter").click(function (e) {

    var offset = $("#imgtoCenter").offset();
    var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
    var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);

    sessionStorage.removeItem('x' + toEdit);
    sessionStorage.removeItem('y' + toEdit);
    document.getElementById("inputRow" + toEdit).style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    document.getElementById("inputRow" + toEdit).style.color = "#000";
    sessionStorage.setItem('x' + toEdit, Math.round(relativeX));
    sessionStorage.setItem('y' + toEdit, Math.round(relativeY));
    document.getElementById("x" + toEdit).value = sessionStorage.getItem('x' + toEdit);
    document.getElementById("y" + toEdit).value = sessionStorage.getItem('y' + toEdit);
});
```

}

If I console.log(id), I've got the value of my last click and the new one.

Thanks.. !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [jQuery click documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

> Additional Notes:
>   As the .click() method is just a shorthand for .on( "click", handler ), detaching >is possible using .off( "click" ).

Each time you're calling `editTicket` method, you're attaching a click event on `#imgtoCenter` element. All theses click events accumulate on the element, and when you're clicking on `#imgtoCenter`, all the handlers are fired with the previous ids they kept.

Just `$("#imgtoCenter").off('click')` at the end of `editTicket` method.

Comment: This is it ! Thanks a lot